# why I'm getting the value of ID as Undefined in the below code?react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

//when i'm trying to console the id everytime I'm getting undefined.I believe it is in the scope but still whgy i'm getting undefined

```
function App() {
  let id;

  let [time, settime] = useState('');

  function timechnage() {

    id = setInterval(() => {
      settime(Date);
    }, 1000);

  }


  function timecage() {
    console.log(id);

    console.log(id);

    settime(0);
  }

  return (

    <div>
      <p>time is {time}</p>
      <button onClick={timechnage}>start</button>
      <button onClick={timecage}>reset</button> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It is out of scope I think. Try Console.log in function timechange

Comment: inside timechange function I'm getting the id value,but why I'm not getting the value of id in the timecage function

Comment: The scope is defined by curly braces and it is outside those

Answer (score 1):

`id` is recreated every time the component updates, therefore its previous value is lost.

To preserve the value of `id` during the lifetime of your component, you need to put it in a `ref`:

```
// Create the ref
const id = useRef();

// Assign it
id.current = setInterval(...

// Display it
console.log(id.current)
```

Comment: got it.
Thank u so much